# C++-17 variadic template: capture both return type and argument types for a callback argument

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I've spent many weeks on this puzzle and thought I might offer it as a challenge to the C++ variadic template crowd here.  If it can be done I bet you'll show me how in about 10 seconds.

Suppose I have a collection of functions in C++ 17, each with its own return type (or void) and each with its own argument types.  For simplicity, a mix of POD arguments and pointers to classes, variable numbers of args, etc.  So two examples:

```
int somefunc(int x, double d) { return x + (int)d; }
void otherfunc(Foo *a, Bar *b, int x) { ... }
```

My goal is to do static compile-time reflection without annotation by building a variadic function that captures the full set of types here.  So for discussion, we can say that our function is of type RT f(T1 a, T2 b, ...).  My context is that I'm building a new (and far better) data marshalling layer for an RPC and multicast system, and these callbacks actually will be done on receipt of a byte array, which I need to demarshall and transform into things of the proper types: an int extracted from the first bytes of my byte array, or a new Foo(char*) where Foo itself has a factory method doing the lifting, etc.

What do I mean by static reflection?  I want a const std::list, where I might put things like typeid(RT).hash_code() into my Info class, or perhaps a pointer to a constructor for each of my categories of arguments (a POD constructor would basically cast the incoming byte sequence to an int* and then return the int; a class constructor would call the factory method).

OK, long preamble, now the failed attempt:  Here's my try.  C++17 doesn't like it at all (seems to bind RT correctly but is unable to bind Rest, perhaps because Rest is actually a list of argument types within the overall function type that RT captures).  Any ideas?

```
class Info
{
       int rt, at;  Info *next;
       Info(int r, int a, Info* nxt) { rt = r; at = a; next = nxt; }
};

template<typename RT>
Info *Scan(RT cb())
{
       return nullptr;
}

template<typename RT, typename T, typename Rest...> Info* Scan(RT cb(T x, Rest... args))
{
       return new Info(typeid(RT).hash_code(), typeid(T).hash_code(), Scan<RT, Rest...>(cb(args...));
};

int TestMethod(int x, int y)
{
       return 0;
}

int main()
{
       Scan(TestMethod);
       return 0;
}
```

Comment: `template<typename RT, typename T, typename Rest...>` <- the `...` should be *before* `Rest`. What you want to do is doable in c++11, working on it atm.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a separate class or recursion for this, you could just return a `std::array` of the hash codes by expanding the argument parameter pack over the `hash_code` call:

```
template <typename RT, typename... Args> 
std::array<size_t, (sizeof...(Args) + 1)> 
Scan (RT (*) (Args...)) 
{
    return { typeid(RT).hash_code(), typeid(Args).hash_code()... };
}
```

Comment: Very cool.  I'll try this and see if I can turn it into what I'm after.

Comment: (Beyond the hashcodes, I also need to create a list of the factory methods, which is kind of a pain because, unless I just don't get that aspect either, C++17 won't let me take the address of a (char*) constructor in a class, because of its rule that memory has to be allocated before the constructor can be called.  I'm thinking of using a lambda that calls new for this....)

Comment: @KenBirman You can't take the address of any kind of constructor. Constructors don't have names, so you can't access them directly. Using a lambda is a possibility, but I'd recommend just returning a value rather than calling `new`. Note however that the type of closures is unspecified, so you would need to store them in a template class or use `std::function` or something.

Comment: Yup, figured that out.  C# is easier in that respect.  But if I can create a template factory method and then maybe cast it to type void*, I think this would accomplish the same thing: in comes my byte array, I call the factory and it creates a foo*, I cast it to void* (because at runtime I won't have the types...) and then I can invoke my method as a variable args method, just passing the POD objects and the void* pointers.  So unsafe code at that step...  And then I need to have the class tell me how big its marshaled representation is, but that's easy.

Comment: @KenBirman Sure, I'd need to see the code to make other suggestions if you want any, but this sounds possible.

Comment: Your suggested answer works; voted it up.  Thanks!  I'll struggle for a bit and won't come back here unless I get solidly wedged again.

Comment: @KenBirman Feel free to grab me in chat if you want bits of help which don't justify a new question!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <typeinfo>

class Info
{
    int rt, at;  Info *next;
public:
    Info(int r, int a, Info* nxt) { rt = r; at = a; next = nxt; }
};

template<typename RT>
Info *Scan() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename RT, typename arg, typename ...args>
Info *Scan() {
    return new Info(typeid(RT).hash_code(), typeid(arg).hash_code(), Scan<RT, args...>());
}

template<typename RT, typename ...Rest> Info* Extracter(RT (&)(Rest...))
{
    return Scan<RT, Rest...>();
}

int TestMethod(int, int)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Extracter(TestMethod);
    return 0;
}
```

This uses the linked `Info` structure. I used one function to extract all the arguments of the targetted function, then another one to enumerate those one by one. No need to carry the function over all the calls.

TartanLlama's answer is more elegant though.